# PowerMgr.exe cannot find module at start up - how to avoid popup?

Tags: windows-10

I have a Windows 10 build 1909 where I apparently have tinkered with something I shouldn't - probably in power management - so now I get a dialog box at startup.

[image: powermgr.exe]

(Danish text:  PowerMgr.exe:  0x0000007e: The stated module was not found)

How do I fix this?

Comment: What exactly did you tinker with?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment and provide the necessary information required to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Find the driver on the manufacturer's support site and download it. It will be worthwhile to download BIOS at the same time.

Go to Device Manager and find the Power Driver.  Uninstall it, restart the computer and install the new driver that you downloaded.  The install will likely demand another restart.

Now, open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.  Run in Order:

dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup

dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

SFC /SCANNOW

Restart once more and test the system.

Note: My computer (Lenovo) has added a 2nd power management app. If this is your case, download both, uninstall both, restart and install both.

Good luck. If the tinkering was not excessive, this should work fine.